# Drag and drop: changing the background

Tags: jquery, background, drag-and-drop

I have a page with a draggable object called `#elementoDraggabile`.

When I move `#elementoDraggabile` in the x axis I would like also to change 
the background of another object `#elementoDroppable`

for example when the position of `#elementoDraggabile` is `x = 1`, the background color of `#elementoDroppable` would be `green` and when `#elementoDraggabile` would be `x = 2` then the background color of `#elementoDroppable` should be `orange`. 
Somebody can help me?

Here my example: http://goo.gl/H3zmj

---

OK, new file: http://goo.gl/P1saz

The color of `#droppable` change on hover. Is it possible change his background without hover but when I'm dragging `#draggable`? Probably i have to modify this line: `$("#draggable").on("hover",function(){`. Is it right?

Thanks to all!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the API, and for example use the [`drop` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) of the droppable element that is fired every time you drop the element, to change the color of the destination.

here's simple example:

> http://jsbin.com/udijul/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event and [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) function.

```
$("#draggable").on("hover",function(){

var p = $("#draggable");
var position = p.position();

if(position.left >10)
{
    $("#droppable").css("background-color","green");
}
        if(position.left >20)
                {
                    $("#droppable").css("background-color","orange");       
                }

    });
```

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/jm8AG/